# Problem with addSelect() doctrine repository. Many to Many relation

Tags: doctrine, repository, many-to-many, symfony5

I have symfony 5, doctrine 2and  php 7.3

Four entities :

1. OrderworkMeeting who contain one Meeting
2. Meeting who contain multiple MeetingUsers,
3. MeetingUser who contain one User and one Meeeting(for many to many relationship between Meeting and User)
4. User

When i do a request in OrderworkMeeting repository to get all OrederworkMeeting with one specific user, doctrine return only one user, impossible to view others users in same meeting ???.

I think it's bug because if i duplicate the request before this but without specific user, it's work !

here is the code :

```
    $list = $repo_om->getByUser([15]);
    foreach ($list as $oo) {
        var_dump(count($oo->getMeeting()->getUsers()));
    }
```

Return 1

```
    $listForNothing = $repo_om->getByUser();

    $list = $repo_om->getByUser([15]);
    foreach ($list as $oo) {
        var_dump(count($oo->getMeeting()->getUsers()));
    }
```

Return 2

And in my OrderworkMeetingrepository :

```
public function getByUser($userId=0){
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('om');
    $qb ->leftJoin('om.meeting', 'm')
        ->addSelect('m')
        ->leftJoin('m.users', 'mu')
        ->addSelect('mu')
        ->leftJoin('mu.user', 'u')
        ->addSelect('u');

    $this->setQbListLink($qb);
    $this->addQbOtherListLink($qb);

    if($userId){
       $or = $qb->expr()->orX();
       $or->add('u.id IN (:id)');
       $qb->setParameter('id', $userId);
       $qb->andWhere($or);
    }

    ->orderBy('m.date', 'DESC');
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

What's append i don't understand ?
Your help is welcome, i think i'm fools :)

Thanks in advance

**Edit:**

After other test in my project, i saw that my doctrine queries have explosed :

with addSelect() : 16 queries, 
without : 84 queries.

So i really need addSelect to reduce queries !

I don't understand why this resolve my problem when i remove addSelect ? I read that addSelect "merge" fields of query but How and why this change my result ? 
Is that came from fields name ?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Any particular reason for the added `addSelect` statements? Simply doing Joins until you get the ability to query users (e.g. in your MtM join-entity) would suffice. So: `->createQueryBuilder('om')->join('om.meeting', 'm')->addCriteria((new Criteria)->expr()->contains('mu.users', $users))->getQuery()->getResult();` (blindly typing that with a glass (or 3), should be about it I think though... )

Comment: Also, as by the looks of it, it concerns a repository function, make the function require an array of users: `/** @var User[] $users */ public function getByUsers(array $users): array {...}` (or singular: `public function getByUser(User $user): array {...}` - but not by an id `int` - too messy (opinion)

Comment: Thanks rkeet for reply, i remove addSelect and it's work. It's a very big project, and i use this addSelect everyWhere without any problem ... I don't know why. For the case of array / int, this is a mistake of example. Thanks a lot !